# How to create a Trigger that is active only during a specified time period and at the end it drops itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I want to prevent users from modifying my table (tblActor) from Time_1 to Time_2. I have two further restrictions:

1. I want the trigger to be dropped automatically after the ending time.
2. I do not want to use Job Agent.

How can I do this?

Comment: why are you trying to block out a time to prevent user updates?

Comment: The reason 'why' I want to do this is irrelevant to the question. The question is 'how' I can do this.

Comment: DDL and DML shouldn't really be mixed.  [This MSFT article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/056367f6-e368-4aa9-bed9-663ba3c18005/self-dropping-trigger?forum=transactsql) suggests using a service broker to do it.

Comment: It seems to be helpful xQbert. I'm reading the article and I'm going to try it. Thanks!

Comment: if we have a WHY then we might be able to suggest  a better alternative than a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop it from within itself.
The catch is that you need at least one event to occur after the end time in order to activate the trigger.

---

Demo

```
create table t (i int)

Go

create trigger t_trg ON t
Instead of insert
AS
begin
    insert into t (i) select -i from inserted
    drop trigger t_trg
end
```

---

```
insert into t(i) values (1)    
select * from t
```

> -1

```
delete t    
insert into t(i) values (1)
select * from t
```

> 1